# Mouse events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent

How would I go about making an image follow the mouse using JavaScript? I'm currently working with the new HTML5 canvas element. (The image I want the mouse to follow is on the canvas, I just want it to follow the mouse's position.)

Answer (score 1):

You can tie the image's position to the `onmousemove` event, you can see my demo here for doing that with regular JavaScript: http://jsbin.com/ogabi3/2

Things like jQuery UI's [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) utility will help provide collision detection with the browser